# Stopping DispatcherTimer when switching app (Windows Store)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I have `DispatcherTimer` in my app which counts how long my app has been active and I'd like to call `DispatcherTimer.Stop()` when user navigates to other app (so it doesn't count anymore). And then resume counting when user goes back to my app.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Suspending event of the Application class, execute the method DispatcherTimer.Stop().

In the Resuming event of the Application class, resume the DispatcherTimer.

The Suspending event of the Application class will execute when the user switches apps or just navigates away from your application. The Resuming event will execute when the user focuses your app and brings it to the foreground.

See: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.resuming.aspx

Comment: actually i've tried that way, but when i run it in Debug mode and go back to Visual Studio (without stopping app ofc) it still prints time to output (so `DispatcherTimer.Tick` keeps running...)

Comment: When in debug mode, you have to force the Application to Suspend and Resume by using the menu located under the debug target drop-down. That is why you don't see it suspend or resume.

Comment: Ah... i thought that it may be one of possibilities... ^^
Hope that it'll work :) Thanks